# USING if statement do not work as it should

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have an `if` statment used in my code but the logic of the code do not work as it should what I want is that when the user enter the city name without entering the district name the system must display an error message

and when the user enter the city name and the district name without entering the lat and long the system must display an  error message .

what it hapen in my code is that even if the user enter the city and lat an long the system display an error message inform the user to enter the lat and long

## code:

```
if($_POST['city'])
{
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $long = $_POST['long'];

    if($_POST['dist'] =="")
    {
        $errorMSG = "you can not add city without having relation with district";
    }
    if($lat || $long ==""){ $errorMSG = "You can not add village Without its coordination";}
    else
    {
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO village (id, village_name, district_id, lattitude, longitude)VALUES('', '$city', , '$lat',  '$long')")or die(mysql_error());
        echo $city;
    }
}
```

Comment: The original [MySQL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if($lat || $long =="")` should be `if($lat=="" || $long =="")`

Comment: missed by few seconds :P

Answer (score 2):

Change this:-

```
if($lat || $long =="")
```

to

```
if($lat =="" || $long =="")
```

Explanation :-

What you were doing is checking if $lat is not empty or $long is empty. Learn about the precedence of operators. == have higher precedence than  ||

Answer (score 2):

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.
And there are some logical errors in it.

The right code using [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) would be

```
if($_POST['city'])
{
    $errorMSG = '';
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $lat  = $_POST['lat'];
    $long = $_POST['long'];
    $dist = $_POST['dist']

    if(!$dist)
    {
        $errorMSG .= "you can not add city without having relation with district";
    }
    if(!$lat || !$long)
    {
        $errorMSG .= "You can not add village Without its coordination";
    }

    if (!$errorMSG)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO village VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $pdo->execute(array($city,$dist,$lat,$long));

    }
}
```

Comment: sir iam new to using mysql or database in general but as i see its so easy to learn PDO  thank you for your help   what is better to use MYSQLI OR PDO???

Comment: if i have to fetch the query or to do num _rows how to use it in my code??

Comment: exactly the same way as you did it with mysql - find yourself a tutorial to learn from and remember that manual page is your best friend