# i have 3 if statment that include 3 queries related to each other by foreign keys the system display error message how to fix it?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

i have three if statment that query 3 tables and each table have a foreign key from the table before  but the problem that the system do not take the foreign of the other table (id) instead it make the value 0

the idea behind this code is the user enter the gov name and click add then the system insert the gov name ......if the user enter the dist name without entering the gov name the system display error msg  else the system insert both value (**but in the dist table in governorate_id field the system enter 0 not the right id of the governorate id** ) so when i try to enter $dist in the third the system display **Undefined variable: dist in**.

so how to fix this error ??

## code:

```
   if(isset($_POST['add']))
   {
       if(isset($_POST['gov']) || isset( $_POST['dist']) || isset($_POST['city']) || isset( $_POST['lat']) || isset($_POST['long']) == "" )
       {
         $errorMSG = "you must fill one of these fields befor you submit!!";
       }

       if($_POST['gov'])
       {
           $gov = $_POST['gov'];
           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO governorate (governorate_id, governorate_name)VALUES('', '$gov')")or die(mysql_error());
           echo $gov;
       }
       //******for adding district*********************//
       if($_POST['dist'])
       {
           $dist = $_POST['dist'];
           $gov = $_POST['gov']; 
           if($_POST['gov'] !=="")
           {
           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO districts (district_id, district_name, governorate_id)VALUES('', '$dist', '$gov')")or die(mysql_error());
           echo $dist;
           }
           else{ $errorMSG = "You can not add District Without relate a Governorate for this district";}
       }
       //********************for adding city****************************//
       if($_POST['city'])
       {
           $city = $_POST['city'];
           $lat = $_POST['lat'];
           $long = $_POST['long'];

           if(!$dist)
           {
               $errorMSG = "you can not add city without having relation with district";
           }
           if($lat =="" || $long ==""){ $errorMSG = "You can not add village Without its coordination";}
           else
           {
           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO village (id, village_name, district_id, lattitude, longitude)VALUES('', '$city', '$dist' ,'$lat',  '$long')")or die(mysql_error());
           echo $city;
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: please rephrase your question

Comment: @ Ofir Baruch what you mean ??

Comment: I cannot even fathom the logic behind this code. Can you please explain what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question YOU asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665148/using-if-statement-do-not-work-as-it-should , are you trying to get everyone else to write your code for you?

Comment: @Nicholas King  no sir this is not a duspliacte question it is a different question because it is a diferrent problem that i face   and i explain what i am expecting to happen as  you suggest

Answer (score 0):

if each pk is defined auto-increment use `mysqli_insert_id` and don't use mysql function they are deprecated.